# Can't use an IF ... THEN ... ELSE inside my CASE statment SQL state: 42601

Tags: postgresql, if-statement, case, plpgsql

I would like to building an insert query on the fly. Here I am collecting all column names. Some columns would only need to be scrambled, and some would need to be decrypted, scrambled and encrypted.

My idea was to check if the column name is in the provided array, and if it is, check to see if its value start with 'pi2'. If so, the apply the necessary transformation decrypt, translate, encrypt. else just translate the value. 
Here is my query:

```
select
case    when column_name = ANY(ARRAY['a', 'pi2_b', 'pi2_c', 'd', 'e'])
    then   (  
     if (substring(column_name from 0 for 4) = 'pi2')  
        then 'my_function.my_encrypt(translate(my_function.my_decrypt('||column_name ||'), '''|| var_scramble_key1 ||''','''|| var_scramble_key2 ||'''))';
     else 'translate('||column_name||','''|| var_scramble_key1 ||''','''|| var_scramble_key2 ||''')';
     end if; ) 
   else column_name end
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'my_temp'
and table_name = 'table_a'
order by ordinal_position ASC
```

Running this query gives me a syntax error:

> at or near 'then' SQL state: 42601 Character: 177.

My question is why can't I use the `IF THEN ELSE` inside my `CASE` statement.

I have this workaround:

```
select
case    when column_name = ANY(ARRAY['a', 'pi2_b', 'pi2_c', 'd', 'e']) AND substring(column_name from 0 for 4) = 'pi2'  
        then 'my_function.my_encrypt(translate(my_function.my_decrypt('||column_name ||'), '''|| var_scramble_key1 ||''','''|| var_scramble_key2 ||'''))';
     when column_name = ANY(ARRAY['a', 'pi2_b', 'pi2_c', 'd', 'e']) 
 then 'translate('||column_name||','''|| var_scramble_key1 ||''','''|| var_scramble_key2 ||''')';

  else column_name end
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'my_temp'
and table_name = 'table_a'
order by ordinal_position ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `IF` is not an SQL key word.
The key word `IF` is valid in PL/pgSQL but not *within* an SQL statement.
`CASE` happens to be valid in both (but there are subtle syntax differences!)

- [Conditionals in PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS)
- [`CASE` statement in SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE)

Comment: This is where I got confused, I am inside a function in PL/pgSQL the result of my query above is being saved to a variable like this.   `var_insert_statement = 
ARRAY(...);`  I am guessing, though I am using PL/pgSQL, I cannot insert PL/pgSQL keyword inside a query.

Comment: @QuoVadis: You are guessing right. Inside an SQL statement only SQL syntax is valid.